# Why my CSS button is not working?

Tags: html, css

I have a background img 120x30, but it's not showing in the full size..why?

Please look here http://f1u.org/en - under each article readmore button.

Comment: Ok seriously, it's impossible to know what you mean with this information..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<a>` is an `inline element`. So, an `inline element` in not take `height, width , vertical margin & vertical padding` in it's.

Then we have to define `display:block` in the `css` like this:

```
.comments-link, .readmore-link {
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: What is the question and how (in the HelloWorld) does this answer..

Answer (score 2):

Add `display: block;`

```
.comments-link, .readmore-link {
        background: url("images/readmore.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        border: medium none;
        display: block;
        font-size: 11px;
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        padding: 0;
        text-indent: 8px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        width: 120px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The a tags are inline elements so width won't apply, they will automatically resize depending on content. If you change the display to block then you can control the elements width and height and should see the image. You might want to also float them so if you have the comments link and read more link they will be displayed side by side. Add the following to your style sheet:

```
.comments-link, .readmore-link {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```